# How can I display a short/custom version of a date in mvc3 razor dropdown?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a drop down that only needs to show Month/Day/Year, without time. Its bound to a IEnumerable<DateTime> supplied by the Model. With default approach a long date is shown:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedDate", new SelectList(Model.Dates, Model.SelectedDate));
```

producing '6/24/2013 12:00:00 AM' for textfield of each list item in dropdown.

How can I show a short date for the text field like so:

'6/24/2013'

I would like to stick to DateTime struct for the model Data, but i guess, i could generate a custom list of objects with custom properties and run the following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedDate", new SelectList(Model.DisplayDates, "Value", "ShortDate", Model.SelectedDate));
```

But maybe there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: If Model.SelectedDate is of type DateTime you can call Model.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString()

Comment: Its actually ToString("d"), but how do i feed it to the drop down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, this is the only ugly solution I find that works for customizing drop down list for DateTime objects without losing ability to set selected date on the drop down.

Using simple wrapper class around DateTime object:

```
public class DisplayDateTime
{
    private DateTime dt;
    private string shortDate;

    public DisplayDateTime(DateTime d)
    {
        dt = d;
        shortDate = dt.ToString("d");
    }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get
        {
            return dt;
        }
    }

    public string ShortDate
    {
        get
        {
            return shortDate;
        } 

    }
}
```

Which is then used by model:

```
    public List<DisplayDateTime> GetDisplayDates()
    {
        var displayDates = new List<DisplayDateTime>();
        foreach (var d in Dates)
        {
            displayDates.Add(new DisplayDateTime(d));
        }

        return displayDates;
    }
```

And then fed to razor like so:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedDate", new SelectList(Model.GetDisplayDates(), "Date", "ShortDate", Model.SelectedDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy, iterate through it, change the dates to a better fit

```
@{
 List<string> shortDates = new List<string>();
 for (var i = 0; i < Model.Dates.Count; i++)
 {
  shortDates.Add(Model.Dates.ElementAt(i).ToShortDateString());
  }
}
```

Use the copy

```
@Html.DropDownList("SelectedDate", new SelectList(shortDates, Model.SelectedDate));
```

Comment: Yeah, that is a solution to shorten the date. However, it will not select the date when used like this.

Comment: Just to clarify, Model.SelectedDate doesn't affect selection of value in the list. It defaults to first item. I went with wrapping the DateTime with custom class. Ugly, unelegant, but so far only way I can see where it works without losing razor functionality.